# Amazon EMR does not add SSH port 22 inbound rule as explained in the documentation?

Tags: ssh, emr, aws-security-group

My understanding of the [EMR Managed Security Group Documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/ElasticMapReduce/latest/ManagementGuide/emr-man-sec-group-rules.html) is that on creation of a cluster, an inbound rule to SSH from any IP to Master on port 22 is added.

> SSH   TCP 22 (public subnets only)    0.0.0.0/0
>
> Allows inbound access to the master node via SSH from any IP address.
>   This rule can be edited to limit access to individual IP addresses or
>   address ranges.

However, I find that is not the case. I had to create an additional security group with SSH on port 22 and specify that in my cluster creation step.

Have I misunderstood the documentation? My concern is that I didn't correctly use the default security group and my 'additional security group' is a hack

Comment: Did you create your cluster in a public subnet (default route goes to IGW)?

Comment: @ChristopherB: sigh, you are right, rereading the excerpt, my cluster may not be in a public subnet.

Comment: Did you manage to resolve this? My public subnet has the default 0.0.0.0/0 route to the IGW but is still not adding for ssh.

Comment: @NoraOlsen: I just created an additional security group with explicit SSH port 22 inbound rule and added that in my cluster creation step. I think you could do that or modify the existing security group